# TRIG: Amplitude and Period of a Cosine Function / Identity

Tags: trigonometry

Determine algebraically the amplitude and period of the following function: $$y=\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} + \theta\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} - \theta\right)$$

Can someone please explain step by step what to do to get the amplitude and period.

Comment: Have you tried expanding using compound angle formulas?

Comment: Can you help me with how to do that? I am not exactly aware of how to use the compound angle formulas...

Comment: $\cos(A\pm B)=\cos A\cos B\mp\sin A\sin B$

Comment: what would i input for the A and B variables?

Comment: i've never done this type of a question before hence why im not sure how to go about solving it

Comment: would you be able to provide me with a step-by-step on how to find the amplitude and period please?

Comment: Substitute $3\pi/4$ for $A$ and $\theta$ for $B$ in the angle addition and subtraction formulas for cosine that David Quinn wrote above.

Comment: okay so now i have cos(3pi+/- theta) = cos 3pi/4 * cos theta +/- sin 3pi/4 * sin theta

Comment: how would i proceed?

Comment: @DavidQuinn  N. F. Taussig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$\cos\frac{3\pi}{4}\cos\theta-\sin\frac{3\pi}{4}\sin\theta+\cos\frac{3\pi}{4}\cos\theta+\sin\frac{3\pi}{4}\sin\theta$$
$$=-\sqrt{2}\cos\theta$$
So the amplitude is $\sqrt{2}$ and the period is $2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

As David suggested in the comments:

$$\cos (A \pm B ) = \cos A \cos B \mp \sin A \sin B$$

So expanding your expression the $\sin$ terms cancel and we have

$$y = 2 \left(\cos \frac{3 \pi}{4}\right) \cos \theta = - \sqrt{2} \cos \theta.$$

Now it's in a form that you can verify by inspection that the amplitude is $\sqrt{2}$ and the period is $2 \pi$.

Comment: would the amplitude not be 1?

Comment: The amplitude is the absolute value of the coefficient out front.